# display json in popup returning ActionResult

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a custom controller in mvc and the ActionResult is:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Details([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest command, int id)
    {
        //var userDetail = _CustomerDetail.GetAllCustomers();
        var genericDetail = _GenericDetail.Table.Where(x => x.EntityId == id).Select(z => new { z.Key, z.Value }).ToList().AsQueryable();
        //var userData = from ud in userDetail
        //               join gd in genericDetail
        //               on ud.Id equals gd.EntityId
        //               select new { gd.Key, gd.Value };
        DataSourceResult result = genericDetail.ToDataSourceResult(command);

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


    }
```

which is returned an object like this:
`{"Data":[{"Key":"Gender","Value":"F"},{"Key":"FirstName","Value":"h"},{"Key":"LastName","Value":"h"},{"Key":"DateOfBirth","Value":"1914-05-03"}],"Total":4,"AggregateResults":null,"Errors":null}`

and my ajax and bootstrap popup codes are:

```js
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/UserDetails/Details",
            data: { id: dataItem.Id },
            success: function (result) {
                $('#dvDetail').html(result);
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
                
        },
        error:function(){
            alert('fail');
        }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">User Detail</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="dvDetail"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to display my json object returning in 2 columns which are Key and Value and try many solutions of `stackoverflow` but did not success.
can anybody help me?

Comment: you have an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give that object a template to render the data as a two column table/div, etc.

You can define a template function like this:

```
userDetailTemplate = function(data){
  var renderRow = function(val){
    return "<tr>" + val + "</tr>";
  }
  var renderCol = function(val){
    return "<td>" + val + "</td>";
  }
  var renderContent = function(val){
    return "<table>" + content + "</table>";
  }
  var content = [];

  for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    var key = renderCol(data[i].Key);
    var val = renderCol(data[i].Value);
    content.push(renderRow(key+val)); 
  }
  return renderContent(content.join(''));
}
```

In the Ajax callback, you need to call this template function.

```
    success: function (result) {
      $('#dvDetail').html(userDetailTemplate(result.Data)); // or this should be result. You need to try either of these.
      $('#myModal').modal('show');      
    },
```

Comment: i dont know why browser catch this error!!  ` Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property "length" of undefined`

Comment: Could you add `console.log(JSON.stringify(result));` before the `$('#dvDetail').html(userDetailTemplate(result.data))` and see what logs there?

Comment: {"Data":[],"Total":0,"AggregateResults":null,"Errors":null}

Comment: It seems like you don't have any `id` that matches  the ` data: { id: dataItem.Id },` here. Could you also check the database and the dataItem.id to see whether they are the same?

Comment: i did some changing and now console return this log:  `{"Data":[{"Key":"Gender","Value":"M"},{"Key":"FirstName","Value":"aaa"},{"Key":"LastName","Value":"aaa"},{"Key":"DateOfBirth","Value":"1911-02-01"}],"Total":4,"AggregateResults":null,"Errors":null}`  
but still have this error:  
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property "length" of undefined

Comment: Oh, my bad, it should be `$('#dvDetail').html(userDetailTemplate(result.Data))` here instead of a downcased 'data'.

Comment: "result.Data" and "result.data" are not the same here, because what returns from the server is in titlecased.